# OO Profile picture upload through PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have developed a registration form using object-oriented techniques, it works fine except when I try and incorportate a file upload so that the user can have a picture saved in the database.

In my database I am using the BLOB format and using **file_get_contents** to retrieve the file uploaded.

I previously had `$profilepic = $_POST['photo'];` which is why `$_POST['photo']` is still in the second if statement.

I'm a little confused what format to use as I've not done a lot of object oriented.

Thanks in advance

```
<center>
<?php
session_start();
include 'registrationform.php';
include 'connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['regsubmit'])) 
    {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $firstname = ucfirst($firstname);
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $lastname = ucfirst($lastname);
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $user = ucfirst($user);
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $spass = $_POST['secondpassword'];
    $profilepic = file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);

    if($_POST['firstname'] && $_POST['lastname'] && $_POST['photo'] && $_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] && $_POST['secondpassword'])
    {
    if ($spass == $pass)
    {
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, photo, username, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('ssbss', $firstname, $lastname, $profilepic, $user, $pass);

    if($statement->execute()){
        print 'Success!'; 
        }else  
        {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
        }
        $statement->close();
        }
        else
        {
           print 'The passwords do not match!';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print 'Enter all fields please';
    }
    }
?>
</center>
```

Comment: Efficient way to do this is move image file to folder using move_uploaded_file() and just store image name in database.

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Thankyou to both, reading up on them now.

Comment: How can i go about doing this Divyesh?

Comment: getting following answer? or still confused?

Comment: Yeah you really need some password security. [Plain text passwords are really, really bad](http://arstechnica.co.uk/security/2015/10/13-million-plaintext-passwords-belonging-to-webhost-users-leaked-online/). On another note, this is not OO code.

Comment: Oh my bad Novocaine! How come? 

And yes thankyou Divyesh, I have accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move uploaded image in folder using [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) and store image name in database.
You can get image name as following:

```
$image_name = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
```

For showing image you can retrieve image name.
Then in html you can show image like following:
`<img src="YOUR_IMAGE_FOLDER_PATH/".$IMAGE_NAME>`